# How to extract column names from multi line strings (or lists)?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have the following string example:

```
column_names = """
    ================================================================================
                                             total                   total     final
    store.                        toys       output   person 1/     usage 5/   stock
    ================================================================================
"""
```

I can break it down line by line like so:

```
column_lines = [
'    ================================================================================',
'                                             total                   total     final',
'    store.                        toys       output   person 1/     usage 5/   stock',
'    ================================================================================',
]
```

Without knowing the text inside the string, I would like to find a way such that I can end up with the following list:

`['store', 'toys', 'total output', 'person', 'total usage', 'final stock']`

I am struggling to find any approach to this.

What are different ways to tackle this problem and how can I extract the strings from multi line text, without knowing what to expect as column names?

Comment: In the first and second cases, the words total and output aren't aligned correctly. How will the input look like exactly? As in, will they be aligned to the left or to the right or both?

Comment: Also, I doubt there's any way to ignore the `1/` and `5/` without straight up replacing them with blank spaces of the same number of characters.

Comment: Good point on the first comment. I have corrected that now - giving both an aligned and non-aligned examples, as both come up.
Regarding the 1/ and 5/, a regex can clean that up I believe.

Comment: Much as I love using regex to solve non-regex questions, I don't believe there's any simple way to achieve the grouping of words using regex. It is however, much simpler to use normal python code to group them. I recommend changing the tags and question to not limit it to regex only, but if for some reason you need regex only, you might have to wait a while for an answer.

Comment: It's possibly easier to fix these issues up the river.

Comment: How would you suggest that as steps @Jan

Comment: @Newskooler: Well, where does the output come from?

Comment: From a txt file. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, one which is definitely longer, but more intuitive according to me. It also allows you to have multiple lines in the input and collates them all together as you'd expect:

```py
import re

column_names = """
    ================================================================================
                                             total                  total     final
    store                         toys       output   person 1/     usage 5/   stock
    name                          toys       here     person 1/     here  5/   stock
    ================================================================================
"""

# Remove those lines
column_names = re.sub(r'\n\s*={2,}', '', column_names)
# Remove newlines from the starting
column_names = re.sub(r'(?<=^)\n+', '', column_names)
# Remove newlines from the ending
column_names = re.sub(r'\n+(?=$)', '', column_names)
# Remove multiple continuous newlines
column_names = re.sub(r'\n{2,}', '\n', column_names)

# Make a list of rows
lines = column_names.split("\n")

# Replace the 1/, 5/ and similar sequences with blank spaces of the same number of characters
for i in range(len(lines)):
    special_tokens = re.findall(r'\d+\/', lines[i])
    for token in special_tokens:
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(token, " "*len(token))

# Make all lines equal width and add a space at the end
max_length = max(len(i) for i in lines)+1
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] += " "*(max_length - len(lines[i]))

# The magic part

i = 0 # i is the index of each character of every row
word_per_line = ['']*len(lines) # Stores the currently active word for each line corresponding to the index
all_entries = [] # Final Output
while i < max_length:
    word_running = False
    for row_index in range(len(lines)):
        current_line = lines[row_index]
        if current_line[i] != " ":
            word_running = True
        word_per_line[row_index] += current_line[i]
    if not word_running:
        # Combine the words of each line so far with a space in between
        combined_entry = " ".join(word_per_line)
        combined_entry = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', combined_entry)
        if combined_entry != " ":
            # All the words exist, so remove leading spaces and add this to all_entries
            combined_entry = combined_entry.strip()
            all_entries.append(combined_entry)
        word_per_line = ['']*len(lines) # Stores the currently active word for each line corresponding to the index

    i += 1

print(all_entries)
```

Again, it's certainly a lot to read at once, but it scales very well with a large number of input lines. Here's another example:

```py
column_names = """
    ================================================================================
                                             total                  total     final
    store                         toys       output   person 1/     usage 5/   stock
    name                          toys       here     person 1/     here  5/   stock
    ================================================================================
"""
```

Gives this output: `['store name', 'toys toys', 'total output here', 'person person', 'total usage here']`

Answer (score 1):

## Basic working solution

Here  is a working solution. We need to specify two lines to "group" together.

```
def find_group(l1, l2):

    def intersect(x1, x2):
        return (x1[0] <= x2[1] and x1[1] >= x2[0]) \
            or (x2[0] <= x1[1] and x2[1] >= x1[0])

    pat = r"[a-zA-Z]+"
    matches1 = [(match.start(0), match.end(0)) for match in re.finditer(pat, l1)]
    matches2 = [(match.start(0), match.end(0)) for match in re.finditer(pat, l2)]

    ret = []
    for g2 in matches2:
        add_g2 = True
        for g1 in matches1:
            if intersect(g1, g2):
                ret.append(l1[g1[0]:g1[1]]+" "+l2[g2[0]:g2[1]])
                add_g2 = False
                break
        if add_g2:
            ret.append(l2[g2[0]:g2[1]])
                   
return ret
```

Here is how it handles your example :

```
find_group(column_lines[1], column_lines[2]) # Needs to define which lines.
# > ['store', 'toys', 'total output', 'person', 'total usage', 'final stock']
```

## General solution

Here is a solution that will work with any amount of lines.

```
def find_group(lines):

    if isinstance(lines, str):
        lines = lines.split("\n")

    def intersect(x1, x2):
        """Checks if two couples of x-coordinates intersect."""
        return (x1[0] <= x2[1] and x1[1] >= x2[0]) \
            or (x2[0] <= x1[1] and x2[1] >= x1[0])

    pat = r"[a-zA-Z]+"
    # Coordinates of all parts matching the pattern, per line
    matches = [[(match.start(0), match.end(0)) for match in re.finditer(pat, line)] 
           for line in lines]

    # Starts by comparing line 0 and line 1
    groups = matches[0]
    for i in range(1, len(lines)):
        for g2 in matches[i]:
            add_g2 = True
            for i_g1, g1 in enumerate(groups):
                if intersect(g1, g2):
                    # Merge both lines intersection into the variable groups
                    groups[i_g1] = [min(g1[0], g2[0]), max(g1[1], g2[1])]
                    add_g2 = False
                    break
            if add_g2:
                # If alone in the x-coord, adds the match as a new group
                groups.append([g2[0], g2[1]])
            # "groups" becomes the merge of the first i lines results.
            
    # Sorts the groups by their first coordinate.
    # Then joins all matches located between each group's coordinates
    listed_groups = [[" ".join(re.findall(pat, line[group[0]: group[1]])) 
                  for line in lines]
                 for group in sorted(groups)]

    # Replaces all unnecessary whitespaces and format groups as strings
    return [re.sub("\s+", " ", " ".join(g).strip()) for g in listed_groups]
```

Result:

```
column_names = column_names = """
================================================================================
some                            I                    each                    hopefully
 kind                         love
 of
                                          total                  total     final
store.                        toys       output   person 1/     usage 5/   stock
================================================================================"""

find_group(column_names)
# > ['some kind of store',
# 'I love toys',
#'total output',
#'each person',
#'total usage',
#'hopefully final stock']
```

Let me know if you want more explanations.